# Calculate Erf function using Horner's Rule (without using factorial and power)

Tags: c++, math

While my first part enables me to use factorial and power, so i create some function prototypes and use recursive function to get the error function as follow:

```
double erf(double x, int N)
{
if (N < 0) return 0;

return 1.128379167*(power(-1,N)*power(x,2*N+1))/((2*N+1)*fact(N))+erf(x, N-1); 
}
```

The problem is that the second part needs me to use Horner's Rule while a1,a2,a3....a(n) include factorial function. So what should I do to change the factorial function into something else, so I could using recursive function to calculate erf without using factorial.

[Horner's rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cah53.png)

[Error function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqVzI.png)

Comment: It's unclear from your description what the problem is. Consider reformulating, please - or showing us more code.

Comment: The problem is about how to link the relationship between these two formulas considering using recursive function or looping

Comment: Try to understand that's a very vague request given almost no code. Try to maybe outline the problem mathematically to see if that makes people understand. I don't know, for instance, what you mean by "these two formulas"

Comment: Can you cache the values of the factorial up to a certain N and use a lookup table? Calculating the factorial for large numbers of N it's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the forward sum as

```
res = 1;
term = 1;
for(k=1; k<=N; k++) {
    term *= -x*x/k;
    res += term/(2*k+1);
}
return 1.128379167*x*res;
```

For a Horner like implementation consider first an example for the inner sum (i.e. without the common factor `1.128379167*x`)

```
1 - x^2/1!/3 + x^4/2!/5 - x^6/3!/7

= 1 - x^2 * (1/3 - x^2/2 * (1/5 - x^2/3 * (1/7 - ...) ) )
```

Thus

```
innersum(x,k,N) {
    if(k>N) return 0;
    return 1/(2*k+1)-x*x/(k+1)*innersum(x,k-1,N);
}

erf(x,N) {
    return 1.128379167*x*innersum(x,0,N);
}
```

Comment: x^6/3!/7 turns into  x^2/3 * (1/7-..... , isn't that should be x^2/3! * (1/7-....

Comment: You need to collect all the factors present in this nested expression.

Comment: sorry I do not quite familiar about using loop  the part 'return 1.128379167*x*res;' and  'return 1.128379167*x*innersum(x,0,N);' So it will not use the common factor twice?

Comment: ok i forget that the inner function will times the outer function so the factorial can be reomved in this way. Now i am trying to type the code in my way to see any problem

Comment: i see the problem maybe the -x*x/(k+1)*innersum(x,k+1,N), it will calculate the -x*x/(k+1)*1/(2*k+2) first. But i understand the whole equation now. Trying to see any coding problem

Comment: seems i cannot find a good way to coding the brackets, any suggestions?